# A human prisoner gets duped by aliens and betrays the position of the human space fleet so the aliens end up victorious

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Saw a TV episode / movie in the 90s with this plot. Can anyone remember the name of this movie / TV show?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could use some more details.  Please check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: You seem happy with the other Outer limits answer but note also: "The Outer Limits" Dead Man's Switch (TV Episode 1997) - IMDb
An American soldier learns that he is one of five people around the world who are separately sealed underground for a year and are charged with preventing Earth's self-destruction as the world awaits a possible invasion by aliens. (He's tricked at the end.)

Comment: Looks interesting too. Thx!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is very little detail in your question so its hard to be certain, but this is possibly an episode of The Outer limits from the mid 1990's called The Quality of Mercy. The plot is very much as you describe.

> Major John Skokes has been captured by the seemingly unbeatable aliens with whom humanity are at war. His companion is a young cadet captured on a training flight, Bree Tristan. Skokes must find a way out of the dank prison for himself and his fellow prisoner before the aliens succeed in converting her to one of their own species.

This plot synopsis comes from the IMDB page for the episode which can be found here...

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667935/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl

You can read about the episode on TV tropes here... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TheOuterLimits1995S1E14QualityOfMercy

Comment: That must be it. Thx!

Comment: Sounds like a rip-off of "Second Variety" by PKD